# YII2.0 table name does not exist

Tags: php, yii2, gii

I am new one for the YII2.0,i like to create a model for the database via GII,
but its throw an error like "table does not exist".

Below attached the screen for your further reference

[image: click the link to view screen shot]

Comment: It says below that "There is no application component named db". Have you checked that the database is configured properly? Take a look in yii config and configure it properly, gii relies on the db connection.

Comment: please configure your database in `config->db.php` file for yii2 basic

Comment: @ScaisEdge Missing `'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),` in configuration.

Comment: Check if localhost/mywebsite/requirements.php looks ok

Answer (score 1):

Configure properly  the basic/config/db.php  eg: like this template

```
<?php

    return [
       'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=yourHostName;dbname=yourDBName',
        'username' => 'yourUserName',
        'password' => 'yourPassword',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
     ];
```

check in your web.php for this

```
$config = [
  'id' => 'basic',
  'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
  'bootstrap' => ['log'],
  'components' => [
      ....
      'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
```

Comment: My configuration is also like above code, do you have any other idea to fix the above mentioned issue

Comment: its default configuration, its already have in YII2.0, i don't change anything on that, i include the db.php file and in my db.php file having the above db config code, do you have any other idea to solve the problem